# MySQL, select to include earlier weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm using the SQL below to get the price history per week from two MySQL database tables:

```
SELECT ROUND(MIN(ph.price), 0) AS min_price, WEEK(ph.added) AS added
FROM products_data pd JOIN products_history ph ON pd.id = ph.product_id
WHERE ph.price > 0
GROUP BY added
ORDER BY added
```

Everything is good, except the `products_history` table only contains entries when a price is changed.

If a week A has a price change that creates the lowest `min_price` in week A, everything is good.

But if the price change happened 1+ weeks before week A, it's not detected by the query and the retrieved lowest `min_price` for week A may therefore not correct :(

Example, what is happening right now:

```
Week 13: Price change so min_price for product A = 4.78,
query returns 4.78 (correct)

Week 14: Price change so min_price for product B = 4.74,
query returns 4.74 (correct)

Week 15: Price change so min_price for product C = 4.79,
query returns 4.79 (wrong, should be 4.74 since that's still the price for product B)

Week 16: Price change so min_price for product C = 4.75,
query returns 4.75 (wrong, should be 4.74 since that's still the price for product B)

Week 17: No price changes,
query returns nothing...  (wrong, should be 4.74 since that's still the price for product B)

Week 18: Price change so min_price for product B = 4.77,
query returns 4.77 (wrong, should be 4.75 since that's still the price for product C)
```

Any ideas for how to make the query retrieve the lowest min_price per week even if the change happend earlier?

---

`products_data` has these columns:

```
id, name, category
2434, 'Product A', 'Bits'
3437, 'Product B', 'Bits'
```

`products_history` has these columns:

```
id, product_id, price, added
4311, 2434, 4.74, 2019-05-15 22:19:50
2434, 3437, 4.78, 2019-05-15 22:19:59
```

---

Working version based on Gordon Linoff's correct answer below:

```
SELECT id, yw.yyyyww,
       (SELECT ph2.price
        FROM products_history ph2
        WHERE ph2.price > 0 AND
              YEARWEEK(ph2.added) <= yw.yyyyww AND ph2.product_id = pd.id
        ORDER BY YEARWEEK(ph2.added) DESC,  -- put the most recent values first
                 ph2.price ASC  -- by lowest price
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS min_price
FROM products_data pd CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT YEARWEEK(ph.added) AS yyyyww
      FROM products_history ph
     ) yw
```

Comment: Sample data as a *text table* in the question and desired results would help explain your question.

Comment: Good point. Added table structures above. Desired results is in the example of what is happening right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a value for every product for every week.  If so, use `cross join` to generate the rows and then -- in MySQL -- you can use a correlated subquery to get the price

```
SELECT product_id, yw.yyyyww,
       (SELECT ph2.price
        FROM products_history ph2
        WHERE ph2.price > 0 AND
              YEARWEEK(ph2.added) <= yw.yyyyww
        ORDER BY YEARWEEK(ph2.added) DESC,  -- put the most recent values first
                 ph2.price ASC  -- by lowest price
       ) as min_price
FROM products_data pd CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT YEARWEEK(ph.added) as yyyyww
      FROM products_history ph
     ) yw
```

Comment: That's super awesome. Thanks a lot for your help. I made a small change or two to make the query match by db structure (will add the final version to my question above).

Comment: The part `ph2.price > 0 AND YEARWEEK(ph2.added) <= yw.yyyyww` has an issue. If the price has been 4.74, 4.79, 4.23 and 4.70 before week X and the latest price before week X is 4.70, the query returns 4.23 since that's the lowest price before week X - but it should return 4.70 since that's the latest price before week X.

Comment: @Mads . . . I thought you wanted the most recent price *by week*.  If you just want the most recent one, then use `ORDER BY ph2.added DESC` in the subquery.